# Identifyng Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client on my passportJS app

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting that error, and besides asking where it is on my code I would like to know if there is a better way to log errors in order to get to know where it is being generated on my code, since I can't figure it out by reading the error log. Here are the code and the error. Thanks! StackOF is making me add more details, I don't know what to write

```
/////// app.js


//Function one : setting up the LocalStrategy
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username" });
            }
            if (bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
                    if (res) {
                        // passwords match! log user in
                        return done(null, user)
                    } else {
                        // passwords do not match!
                        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" })
                    }
                })) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    })
);

//Functions two and three: Sessions and serialization
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

//Route for logging in
app.post(
    "/log-in",
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/"
    })
);


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index", { user: req.user });
});

app.get("/sign-up", (req, res) => res.render("sign-up-form"));

app.post("/sign-up", (req, res, next) => {

    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => {
        // if err, do something
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        // otherwise, store hashedPassword in DB
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        const user = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: hashedPassword
        }).save(err => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            return res.redirect("/");
        });
    });



});


app.get("/log-out", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
});


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("app listening on port 3000!"));
```

And the error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:888:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:926:18)
    at complete (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:266:26)
    at C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:275:15
    at pass (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:431:14)
    at Authenticator.transformAuthInfo (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:453:5)
    at C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:272:22
    at C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:52:7
    at C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:26:5
    at pass (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:277:43)
    at serialized (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:286:7)
    at C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\app.js:63:5
    at pass (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:294:9)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\passportJSOdin\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:299:5)
```

Comment: The error is on line 63 of your `app.js` file. So tell us what's on line 63?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a glaring issue in the logic of your code here:

```
 if (bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
   if (res) {
     return done(null, user)
   } else {
     return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" })
   }
 })) {
 return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
 }
 return done(null, user);
```

`bcrypt.compare()` is an asynchronous function, which means it does not return the result it produces to its calling code, but instead passes it to its callback function once available. So the continuation of the code - ie everything that should happen once the result is available - should be wrapped in its callback function.

You got this right. But then you are duplicating the logic of what happens in this callback function in the calling code based on the returned value of `bcrypt.compare()` - which is irrelevant.

The end result is that the `done()` function will end up being called twice.

You should just do:

```
bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
  if (res) {
    return done(null, user)
  } else {
    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" })
  }
})
```

As far as logging errors, a stack trace is as good as it gets to help pinpoint the issue.